# How to list external identifiers in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, identifier

I have a module in a C project with a bunch of big source and header files. They include a lot of external header files, from libc and other modules of the same project. I would like to collect a list of the identifiers **actually** used from these external header files. Not just symbols, but all the external type definitions, inlined functions, macros etc.

I want to compile a list to see what external dependencies that module have, so I can see what exactly needs to be ported/rewritten/thrown out if I want to move this module into a completely different project. In this particular case I'm not that interested in libc dependencies, but rather the ones from other modules of the same project.

The nearest thing I've got is to temporarily remove the include directives like this:

```
sed -i s/"#include <.*>"//g *.c
sed -i s/"#include <.*>"//g *.h
```

Then compile the files with -Wno-unused, so I can see the error messages due to the missing headers. But it's still far from an easily readable list of external identifiers.

Comment: Why do you care that much about used identifiers? What is the exact motivation of your question? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Even with the edit, I still don't understand your motivation. As soon as you use any external library, you are very likely not using all names in it...

Comment: Exactly, I'm far from using all identifiers from external libraries, I just want to know what exactly is used from those external sources. Because it's still quite a big piece of code with lots of references to outside code, and instead of going through it line by line and collect a list of types/functions/macros used, I want something more automatic. It would help me planning and preparing to swap to another external library, which (as far as I see now) has what this code uses now.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually harder than what you believe (in particular, because [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) tricks like [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) can build symbols, and also because some compiler specific headers -notably `<stdarg.h>`- may rely on GCC builtins or extensions, also GCC accepts [asm labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html), etc..).

<sup>Notice also that the compiler may do [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) like transforming a simple `printf` into a `puts` (what name does count in that case?) ...</sup>

If you really mean what you want, you might customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g. using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), to fit your purposes. That could take several weeks of work.

Another approach might be to parse approximately the preprocessed form, collect the lexical tokens in it, and sort them. You could `flex` to generate the lexer, and write your utility in C++ (or Python, or Ocaml) or whatever; but then it will only produce an approximation of the used names... If you want to parse C++ code it is much harder (namespaces, templates, [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)...).

If you restrict yourself to linker visible symbols, you could of course use [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html) on object files and non-stripped executables.

BTW, GCC can handle the `-M` [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to automatically produce `make` dependencies.

At last, I cannot understand your motivations (even with your latest edit): if you have `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` in some GUI application, you are very likely not using every symbol or identifier defined in GTK... (and likewise, you probably don't use every identifier from `<stdio.h>` or `<unistd.h>`...). In practice, you are quite likely to not use *all* the symbols provided by most external libraries you are using (GTK, sqlite, libcurl, ....)

Perhaps some [cross-referencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-reference) tool like [cxref](http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/cxref/) might be useful.

Comment: Yes, concatenation can really make this harder. Fortunately there are no asm labels in this particular code, and I'm not interested in gcc builtin extensions. For optimizations like printf -> puts change I care about the original identifier. But as I updated in the original question, libc dependencies are not that interesting to me in this particular case.

Comment: I've tried nm too, but it actually the huge part of the functions gets inlined. And it doesn't show macros, type definitions.

Comment: The -M gcc option is also just nearly what I want: it can give me a list of the header files, but not what's used from them.

Comment: To repurpose your GTK example: yes, it's very likely my module is far from using every identifier from GTK, that's why I want to have an exact list of what's used from GTK. So I can see what do I need to care for if I would like to replace GTK with something else.

Comment: But why do you want this. As soon as you are using GTK, you will `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` and link with `$(pkg-config --libs gtk+-x11-3.0)` so I don't see your point. And if you replace GTK by something else (uncompatible), compilation or build will fail if something is missing

Comment: So your solution, if you want it to be failproof, is to customize GCC for your needs. [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) is a useful tool, but you'll need several weeks of work

Comment: In this hypothetical GTK example, I want to know what is used from GTK, so I can see what needs to be changed in my code if I want to use something else than GTK. And also I can see what changes I need to do in my GTK-replacement, what functions/macros/types need to be added. Because I don't want to reimplement the whole GTK, I just want to know what parts of it are actually used.