# Generate single C file from multiple ones

Tags: c, preprocessor

Is there a way (e.g. some script) to generate a single C file out of a main.c including multiple other files? Ideally I want it to pull only definitions of functions and structs that are used in the main.c file, and not just pasting the whole included C file in the beginning. As an example consider the following scenario (assume there are no funny interdependencies between functions and structures, that is declarations are not necessary if the definitions are given in order):

common.h

```
void foo();
void bar();
typedef struct _A {/* definition */} A;
typedef struct _B {/* definition */} B;
```

common.c

```
#include "common.h"
void foo() {/* definition */}
void bar() {/* definition */}
```

main.c

```
#include <math.h>   /* do not pull anything from <...> */
#include "common.h" /* pull only definitions of objects used in main.c */

int main()
{
    A a;
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Then ideally the resulting file should be:

coalesced_main.c

```
#include <math.h>
/* #include "common.h" has been replaced with this: */
void bar() {/* definition */}
typedef struct _A {/* definition */} A;

int main()
{
    A a;
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Suggestions on how I can make myself such a script are also welcome.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Most strive to do the other way around. -- Anyway, the common compiler tools don't provide such a function. Most are able to output the resulting source after preprocessing, for example by the option `-E` for GCC. -- If you need more, take a look into the LLVM project and write your own tool based on it.

Comment: @thebusybee "Why would you want to do this?" - I don't, but it's not up to me. I've done it so many times manually at this point that I figured that maybe it would make sense to automate it. I am aware of the `-E` flag, but I do not want to include anything from `#include <...>` or other redundant functions that `main.c` is not using.

Comment: A homebrew script for this would be pretty difficult to get right (it basically needs to "understand" C to know what is "used" what is not). As for ready-made tool, you can probably find bits and pieces around that can help you analyze the code, but I doubt there is a specific tool which will do it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. This actually helped me rubberduck it a bit. I figured I could make some simplistic copy-paste script by searching for keywords in `main.c` and then adding some metadata including the keyword in the comments to distinguish the beginning/end of a function/struct definition, then this wouldn't need to understand C.

Comment: 1) Analyse the problem 2) Make a program design 3) Write code 4) Test. If you are doing it in any other order, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Lundin Refactoring is a thing. Not sure it is the case here though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah... it's a buzz word used by inexperienced programmers to make them sound smart when they have to re-write everything from scratch due to bad/non-existent program design...

Comment: @Lundin Well.. I am going to disagree with you here. Not going to argue though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I mean, program design is hard and takes lots of experience. One needs some >5 years of full time programmer experience or so to get it somewhat right at design stage. But back in the days when I was a rookie, we still called it "re-write everything from scratch". There was less posing and social media fame back then...

Comment: OK, it's not you who wants it, understood. It does not matter. What makes me wonder, still, _why at all_? What is the gain in your project? -- BTW, from your prose I didn't expect to see the implementation of `bar()` in the result, since "common.c" is not included in "main.c".

Comment: @thebusybee `What is the gain in your project?` - my supervisor not having to deal with multiple files (I have no say in this). I guess I didn't manage to word it out clearly when I said I want it to pull only the definitions, but what you see in the example is the desired behaviour. I.e. whenever a function or struct is encountered in `main.c` it's supposed to check through all the included headers of the form `#include "*.h"` and then pull the definitions (only once and in order) from the respective `*.c` files. I'll just add some metadata in the definitions' comments to be able to do this.

Comment: Oh dear, I see. All the best.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234065/how-to-list-external-identifiers-in-gcc

Comment: You can do this with preprocessor directives, but it would be odd looking with your code wrapped in `#ifdef/#endif`. Alternatively, use comments to show where declarations are, example `//script-begin` `void bar();` `//script-end` A simple script can read those lines and copy to *.h file.